# Set Auto Width base on Contents

Tags: css

I have the following notifications below created with the following CSS code:

**long**

[image]

**Short**

[image]

**CSS**

```
.notifications {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 800;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

---

I'm trying to set an auto width to it base on the text/content in there

Here is my current attempt which I have tried:

**CSS**

```
.notifications {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 800;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.notification .right {
    margin-left: 20%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```

**The result:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about doing something like this

```css
.notifications {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 800;
}

.notification .message {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
}

.notification .message:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="notification"> 
  <div class="message"> 
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
<div class="notification"> 
  <div class="message"> 
    Hello, I'm much longer
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated my **CSS** now I got it to be auto

Keep this one as it is

```
.notifications {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 800;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

---

```
.notification .right {
    margin-left: 20%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 25px; <---- Added Line
}
```

Now I got it

[image]

[image]